# Need LINQ expression to filter table based on foreign key values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table of WorldEvents. Each WorldEvent has a list of Presentations, that happened in some country, regarding that WorldEvent

```
public class WorldEvent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Presentation> PresentationList { get; set; }
}

public class Presentation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class WorldEventService
{
    public List<WorldEvent> GetWorldEvents()
    {
        List<WorldEvent> worldEventList = new List<WorldEvent>();
        List<Presentation> presentationList = new List<Presentation>();

        // Create list of Presentations for WorldEvent_1
        presentationList = new List<Presentation>()
        {
            new Presentation() { ID = 1, Name = "Presentation_1", Country = "Germany",},
            new Presentation() { ID = 2, Name = "Presentation_2", Country = "UK",},
            new Presentation() { ID = 3, Name = "Presentation_3", Country = "UK",},
        };

        // Add WorldEvent_1 to the list of WorldEvents
        worldEventList.Add(new WorldEvent()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Name = "WorldEvent_1",
            PresentationList = presentationList,
        });

        // Create list of Presentations for WorldEvent_2
        presentationList = new List<Presentation>()
        {
            new Presentation() { ID = 4, Name = "Presentation_4", Country = "USA",},
            new Presentation() { ID = 5, Name = "Presentation_5", Country = "UK",},
            new Presentation() { ID = 6, Name = "Presentation_6", Country = "Japan",},
        };

        // Add WorldEvent_2 to the list of WorldEvents
        worldEventList.Add(new WorldEvent()
        {
            ID = 2,
            Name = "WorldEvent_2",
            PresentationList = presentationList,
        });

        // Create list of Presentations for WorldEvent_3
        presentationList = new List<Presentation>()
        {
            new Presentation() { ID = 7, Name = "Presentation_7", Country = "France",},
            new Presentation() { ID = 8, Name = "Presentation_8", Country = "Germany",},
            new Presentation() { ID = 9, Name = "Presentation_9", Country = "Japan",},
        };

        // Add WorldEvent_3 to the list of WorldEvents
        worldEventList.Add(new WorldEvent()
        {
            ID = 3,
            Name = "WorldEvent_3",
            PresentationList = presentationList,
        });

        return worldEventList;
    }
}
```

Now - how can I get a list of WorldEvents, whose Presentations took place in the UK.
And - in the list of my interest, WorldEvents should contain info about those UK Presentations only.
In other word, I need this as result:

1. WorldEvent_1(Presentation_2, Presentation_3)
2. WorldEvent_2(Presentation_5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood what you want. There are many ways to do this, however you can filter first, then recreate your `WorldEvents` with the filtered list of `Presentation`

```
var country = "UK";

var result = worldEventList.Where(x => x.PresentationList.Any(y => y.Country == country))
                           .Select(x => new WorldEvent()
                               {
                                  ID = x.ID,
                                  Name = x.Name,
                                  PresentationList = x.PresentationList
                                                      .Where(y => y.Country == country)
                                                      .ToList()
                                }).ToList();
```

or as noted by [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold) in the comments you could filter after the fact

```
var result = worldEventList.Select(x => new WorldEvent()
                 {
                     ID = x.ID,
                     Name = x.Name,
                     PresentationList = x.PresentationList
                                         .Where(y => y.Country == country).ToList()
                 }).Where(x => x.PresentationList.Any())
                   .ToList();
```

<sub>***Note*** : Because this is not projecting (selecting) each `Presentation`, any change you make to a `Presentation` in the `result` will be reflected in the original data. If you don't want this, you will need to recreate each `Presentation`</sub>

Comment: You could remove `.Where(x => x.PresentationList.Any(y => y.Country == country))` and add `.Where(x => x.PresentationList.Any())` at the end instead, so the predicate can be be added once. This esp. useful when there are more predicates. In LINQ-to-Objects this will execute the Select too often, but in LINQ to a SQL backend (actually used here) this will be translated to SQL that filters in time.

Comment: @GertArnold added and attributed

Answer (score 1):

```
var worldEvent = new WorldEventService.GetWorldEvents();

var filter = "";//userInput

var filteredResult = worldEvent.Select(r => new WorldEvent
                     { 
                         PresentationList = r.PresentationList.Where(c => c.Country == filter).ToList(),
                         ID = r.Id,
                         Name = r.Name 
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Not good, or my description wasnt concise enough (sorry if thats the case). I've altered my code a little - added WorldEvent_3, which has no Presentations in the UK. Your code still returns all 3 WorldEvents, even tho WorldEvent_3 is returned with an empty list of Presentations

Comment: @AlexeyTitov forgot to test it in no UK at bottom, answer above is the correct solution

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<WorldEvent> Filter(string Country, List<WorldEvent> events) {
        var evs = from ev in events.Where(x => x.PresentationList.Any(y => y.Country == Country))
                  let targetPres = from pres in ev.PresentationList
                                   where pres.Country == Country
                                   select pres
                  select new WorldEvent {
                      ID = ev.ID,
                      Name = ev.Name,
                      PresentationList = targetPres.ToList()
                  };
        return evs.ToList();        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my understanding is correct, I guess there's a one to many relationship between your WorldEvent and Presentation table. So if you'd like to get all the WorldEvents and its related Presentations which take place in UK, by using EntityFramework, you can try this:

```
worldEventContext
    .Include(PresentationContext)
    .Select(
        w => new
        {
            w.ID,
            w.Name,
            PresentationList = w.PresentationContext.Where(p => p.Country == "UK")
        })
```